# Including file in Joomla - what is the difference?

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla2.5

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between including the js script file in the following two ways,

I made this inside system plugin in joomla and included the js file inside "onAfterInitialise" function.

1)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>/plugins/system/test/script/script.js"></script>
```

This works fine and including the js file correctly, But when I logged-in from the backend the font size from userlisting and listing from other extensions gets enlarged.This is not the issue in my js script.

2)

```
$document->addScript(JURI::root(). "plugins/system/test/script/script.js");
```

This works fine without any issues.

Can anyone explain what goes behind this.

Comment: Check in the Dom where is the js file called with first and second method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the second method is simply using Joomla coding standards and adds your script in between the `<head>` tags.

There isn't much difference except for where the script gets imported on the page.

`JURI::base()` and `JURI::root()` are both the same. They both define the root folder for your Joomla site. If you are unsure which one to use, I would recommend using method 2, as it's always good to get used to Joomla coding standards.

Comment: Also by using `addScript()` other plug-ins and extensions are able to look at the array of scripts being added (very useful for extensions that want to load JQuery and need to check for existing JQuery libraries being called or for conflicts with others like MooTools).

Comment: Thanks but I tried both on script tag but still issue not fixed

Comment: what's you actual problem? cause I was under the impression that you only wanted to know the difference between method 1 and 2

Comment: Yes, I want to know the difference and also the issue (I logged-in from the backend the font size from user listing and listings from other extensions gets enlarged.) above.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the source of addScript() :) Basicly, if you use first method, your srcipt will be added in the same place you wrote the code. Second method will add link to a inner table in $document and will be 'rendered' at the

```
  <head></head>
```

section at the end of page processing.

Comment: Is there any option to fix it with <script>